# When (deep) Cloning, use String.Copy or str1 = str2?

Tags: .net, string, clone

When (deep) Cloning a custom object, should I use `clone.str1 = String.Copy(obj.str1)` or `clone.str1 = obj.str1`?

I'd prefer the latter - shorter and quicker, but is it "safe"?

I'd point to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520895/whats-the-use-of-system-string-copy-in-net), but, however, not sure what to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - the latter choice (simple assignment) is safe for strings (in managed code), as this code illustrates:

```
    string s1 = "Initial Value";
    string s2 = s1;

    Console.WriteLine("String1: " + s1);
    Console.WriteLine("String2: " + s2);

    s1 = "New Value";

    Console.WriteLine("String1 - after change: " + s1);
    Console.WriteLine("String2 - after change: " + s2);
```

Output:

```
String1: Initial Value
String2: Initial Value
String1 - after change: New Value
String2 - after change: Initial Value
```

Strings are immutable - so when you change s1, you are really creating a new string and assigning it. The reference of s2 remains pointing to the old instance.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, but under the hood it uses unsafe code to do a char copy on the string. This means you are doing an unnecessary copy operation, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `String.Copy` will create a separate copy of the string.
Since strings are immutable, there's no need to do that.

Comment: so, understood, that I can use the a = b. However, is not always safe, by e.g. (from the provided link) : "This may matter if you use the string with unmanaged code which deals with the memory locations directly and can mutate the string."

Comment: Are you really dealing with unmanaged code that mutates a string in-place?

Answer (score 1):

When deep cloning, why not just use a BinaryFormatter instead?

See [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a6f1a7c9-2331-4300-aa82-b1b018fae381).

Here's the code I wrote at that link:

```
public Automobile Clone()
{
    Automobile result = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
         bf.Serialize(ms, this);
         ms.Position = 0;
         result = (Automobile)bf.Deserialize(ms);
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: The trick with the binary formatter is handy, especially for existing classes. However, it is *nowhere near* as fast or memory efficient as writing your own deep clone. It shouldn't be your first choice approach.

Comment: problems with cycle references.

Comment: Cyclic references should be just fine. But non-serializable classes will be a problem.

Comment: @SealedSun: why do you mean "just fine"? I can't binary serialize a object that has a parent.

Comment: @serhio - I haven't checked, but I'm pretty sure (90%) that is only an issue with xml serialization and not binary serialization in .Net.

Comment: There's no problem with cyclic references in binary serialization... and it's fast... and it requires no maintenance... and, if properly implemented, it's reusable across classes.

Comment: you both have reason. This is an interesting way to go. Thanks, David. It's a pity that the question is formulated as is, so I can't make your answer as answer, but is was useful.

Comment: no without problems, however, I use VB.NET, so Handles makes me problems, but found a solution http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/serializevbclasses.aspx

Answer (score 1):

when deep cloning, you need to clone every mutable value. String is mutable on .NET, so yes, you should clone it.

**edit:** whoops ... seems they are immutable, so no, you don't need to.

Comment: @serhio: no, sry, I was wrong. I assumed String is mutable, since it has an insert method, but actually this returns a new string. this is also why clone returns the string itself.

Comment: I understood. However, string is immutable only in the managed code ;)

Comment: @serhio: yeah, ok, if some evil soul from the dark hells of low level languages comes along and tampers with your data, then everything's possible and nothing's valid ... :D